# How to calibrate videre_stereo_camera

Tags: ros, calibration, stereo-calibration, camera-info, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to calibrate a videre stereo camera.I am using the Videre_stereo_cam from ua_drivers package as drivers for the camera.I tried to calibrate the camera by following this tutorial[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration) But  when i am trying to run the node of camera calibrator it is giving the following errors.

Waiting for service /stereo/left/set_camera_info ...

Service not found

Waiting for service /stereo/right/set_camera_info ...

Service not found

When i tried to find the services using rosservice list i actually did not find the services.I am really dont understand how to move forward from here.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10839/how-to-calibrate-videre_stereo_camera/) by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your driver does not support camera info services, pass ''--no-service-check'' to the calibration to skip this.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-08-08**:
Thanks for the reply...